# How to Delete a Directory named as a hadoop command in a VM?

Tags: linux, hadoop, terminal, hdfs, virtual-machine

I have accidentally made a directory named **-mkdir** which a linux command in a VM. Now, I'm unable to remove this directory, I have used the commands hadoop fs -rm -R -mkdir and it is displaying a error **illegal action**. Anyone can help with this issue.

Comment: I am not sure it will work but try ```hadoop -rm -R "-mkdir"```

Answer (score 0):

Use of the `--` option is key to removing the direct.

From the same Linux VM that created the direction, do `rmdir -- -mkdir`. This instructs getop to cease looking for options, so the next file "-mkdir" can be deleted.

```
$ mkdir -- -mkdir
$ ls -ld -- -mkdir
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  7 21:45 -mkdir
$ rmdir -- -mkdir
```